# how to find the duplicates in ArrayList using hashmap in java?

Tags: java, collections

my program is reading large txt files(in MBs) which contain the source ip and destination ip(for example 192.168.125.10,112.25.2.1) ,,,Here read is an ArrayList in which the data is present.
i have generated unique ids(uid int type) using srcip and destip and now i am storing in

```
static ArrayList<Integer[]> prev = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

where Array is 
:-

```
static Integer[] multi1;
multi1 = new Integer[]{(int)uid,count,flag};
```

i have to print the all uids with there count or their frequencies using hashmap.

Plz give some solution...

```
for (ArrayList<String> read : readFiles.values())
    {
        if(file_count<=2)
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i<read.size() ; i++)
            {
                String str1=read.get(i).split(",")[0];//get only srcIP
                String str2=read.get(i).split(",")[1];//get only destIP
                StringTokenizer tokenizer1=new StringTokenizer(str1,".");
                StringTokenizer tokenizer2=new StringTokenizer(str2,".");
                if(tokenizer1.hasMoreTokens()&&tokenizer2.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    sip_oct1=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer1.nextToken());
                    sip_oct2=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer1.nextToken());
                    sip_oct3=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer1.nextToken());
                    sip_oct4=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer1.nextToken());
                    dip_oct1=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer2.nextToken());
                    dip_oct2=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer2.nextToken());
                    dip_oct3=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer2.nextToken());
                    dip_oct4=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer2.nextToken());
                    uid=uniqueIdGenerator(sip_oct1,sip_oct2,sip_oct3,sip_oct4,dip_oct1,dip_oct2,dip_oct3,dip_oct4);
                }
                multi1 = new Integer[]{(int)uid,count,flag};
                prev.add(multi1);
                System.out.println(prev.get(i)[0]);//getting uids from prev
                Map<ArrayList<Integer []> , Integer> map = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer[]>, Integer>();
                for (int j=0 ; j<prev.size() ; j++) 
                {

                    Integer temp=map.get(prev.get(i)[0]);
                    count = map.get(temp);
                    map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count++);
                }
                printMap(map);
                System.out.println("uids--->"+prev.get(i)[0]+"    Count---   >"+count+"     flag--->"+prev.get(i)[2]);

            }
        }
        file_count++;
    }
} 
     public static void printMap(Map<ArrayList<Integer[]>, Integer> map)
     {

    for (Entry<ArrayList<Integer[]>, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(" Value : "+ entry.getValue()+"key : "+entry.getKey());
    }

}


  public static double uniqueIdGenerator(int oc1,int oc2,int oc3,int oc4,int oc5,int oc6,int oc7,int oc8)
{
    int a,b;
    double c;
    a=((oc1*10+oc2)*10+oc3)*10+oc4;
    b=((oc5*10+oc6)*10+oc7)*10+oc8;
    c=  Math.log(a)+Math.log(b);
    return Math.round(c*1000);
}
```

Comment: Are the IP's unique or are the id's?

Comment: In the program i am splitting out the octets(using StringTokenizer) of ips for getting the unique ids,and also ids may be repeating for the same pair of sip and dip

Comment: @Flummox unique ids are like connection ids in networking ...for example during flash crowd on internet.one user may request to same server for multiple times.therefor the connections or uids may be repeating.

Comment: My suggestion: use a custom class to hold "uid", "count", and "flag", defines its `equals()` and `hashcode()` on "uid". This will simplify and probably fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Now understanding what you want, there are (at least) 2 ways of doing this.

1st: Make a list with the uid's. Then a second list where you can have a value (your uid) and keep a count. Was thinking of HashMap, but there you can not easily change the count. Maybe an ArrayList of a list with 2 values.
Then loop over your list with the uid's, check with a second for loop if the uid is already in the second list. If it is, add one to the count. If it is not, add it to the list.

2nd: Do the same thing, but then with classes (very Java). Then you can put even more info into the class ;)

Hope this helps!

*edit: @RC. indeed gives cleaner code.

Comment: ...why can't count be changed??how to access count?

Comment: You need a way to keep count for **each** uid. How do you want to do that? Do you understand classes? I will help you, just not write the code for you.

Comment: actually i want to create self similarity matrix for the info which i am retrieving from the ip adresses those infos are packetRate/connection,and new connection ratio etc. my files are present in a directory in which files are of 1 second data(meaning no. of requests to different servers in 1 second,the requests are huge eg. 241590 requests/files ,i have 60 files to read)...here self similarity means the nature of crowd in a flash traffic on internet.the goal of program is to detect the flash crowd